# Replacing the input with output

Tags: procedural-programming

I have the following code,

```
dx=0.02;
dz=0.05;
Ein[j_,kz_]=2(j dx+kz dz);

For[kz=1, kz<5+1, kz++,
For[j=-5, j<5+1, j++,
Ax[j, kz]= 4/5 (Ein[j+1, kz]-Ein[j, kz]);
];
Ein[j,kz]=Ax[j, kz]
]
```

Why it is not replacing the values of `Ein[j, kz]` with the `Ax[j, kz]`, when running for the next loop `kz > 1`;

I mean how to replace `Ein[j+1, kz]` with `Ax[j+1, kz]` and `Ein[j, kz]` with `Ax[j, kz]`?

Then I need to recall the values of new  `Ein[j,1], Ein[j,4]` etc... at different `kz`..

Comment: Why are you not directly assigning the values to `Ein[j, kz]`, as in `Ein[j, kz]=4/5(...)`? Since the `Ax[j, kz]` only depend on the "current" and "future" `Ein[j, kz]`, you'll never override any values of `Ein[j, kz]` too soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the replacement using the downvalues.

```
dx = 0.02;
dz = 0.05;
Ein[j_, kz_] := 2 (j dx + kz dz);

For[kz = 1, kz < 5 + 1, kz++,
 For[j = -5, j < 5 + 1, j++,
  Ax[j, kz] = 4/5 (Ein[j + 1, kz] - Ein[j, kz])];
 DownValues[Ein] = Join[DownValues[Ein], DownValues[Ax] /. Ax -> Ein]]

vars = Cases[DownValues[Ein], 
  HoldPattern[Ein[x_Integer, y_]] :> {x, y}, Infinity]
```

> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 2}, {-5, 3}, {-5, 4}, ... {5, 4}, {5, 5}}

```
Ein @@@ vars
```

> {0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, ... 0.032, 0.032}

The results do actually come out the same, e.g.

```
kz = 2; j = -5;
4/5 (Ein[j + 1, kz] - Ein[j, kz]) = 4/5 (0.04 - 0.) = 0.032

kz = 1; j = -3;
4/5 (Ein[j + 1, kz] - Ein[j, kz]) = 4/5 (0.02 + 0.02) = 0.032
```